# Actionscript restrict only number with two decimals

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

why it is not simple!

i just want to restrict input text to allow only number with 2 decimals
examples 
22.44 
10.55 
6.00 
55.72

how can i make it with actionscript 2.0
?

bless will raise on the helper!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restrict the characters that can be entered into your text field to the numbers 0 to 9 and the decimal point:

```
textField.restrict = "0-9.";
```

Then add a listener function to the onChanged event, removing everything beyond two characters from the decimal point, or any second occurrence of ".":

```
textField.onChanged = function () {
    var ind = textField.text.indexOf (".");
    if ( ind > -1) {
        var decimal = textField.text.substring (ind+1);
        if (decimal.indexOf (".") > -1) {
            textField.text = textField.text.substring (0, ind + 1 + decimal.indexOf("."));
        }
        if (decimal.length > 2) {
            textField.text = textField.text.substring (0, ind + 3);
        }
    }
}
```